# Unable to run docker-compose file through skaffold in Openshift

Tags: docker-compose, openshift, skaffold

I am trying to run docker-compose file through skaffold using the following command in Openshift,

```
    skaffold init --compose-file docker-compose.yaml
```

This fails while building the project in Jenkins with the following error,

```
    + skaffold init --compose-file docker-compose.yaml --verbosity=info
    time="2019-11-25T07:37:38Z" level=info msg="Skaffold &{Version:v0.37.0 ConfigVersion:skaffold/v1beta13 GitVersion: GitCommit:b3aa6b0a95ea1e87fd8420df195c3c2d35d8341a GitTreeState:clean BuildDate:2019-08-29T20:44:03Z GoVersion:go1.12.9 Compiler:gc Platform:linux/amd64}"
    time="2019-11-25T07:37:38Z" level=info msg="running 'kompose convert' for file docker-compose.yaml"
    time="2019-11-25T07:37:38Z" level=fatal msg="running kompose: exit status 1"
```

I am not able to understand the error and could not find anything from Internet. So, please help me to run the docker-compose file from skaffold in OpenShift.

Comment: Can you try to run `kompose convert docker-compose.yaml`?